# How to add div tag inside get_instance?

Tags: php

I don't have enough knowledge with PHP and I am wondering how can I add a div tag inside the codes below.

```
if ( is_single() ) {

            if (empty($tds_inline_ad_paragraph_mob)) {
                $tds_inline_ad_paragraph_mob = 0;
            }

            $cnt = 0;
            $content_buffer = ''; // we replace the content with this buffer at the end

            $content_parts = preg_split('/(<p.*>)/U', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

            $p_open_tag_count = 0; // count how many <p> tags we have added to the buffer

            foreach ($content_parts as $content_part_index => $content_part_value) {
                if (!empty($content_part_value)) {

                    // Show the ad ONLY IF THE CURRENT PART IS A <p> opening tag and before the <p> -> so we will have <p>content</p>  ~ad~ <p>content</p>
                    // and prevent cases like <p> ~ad~ content</p>
                    if (preg_match('/(<p.*>)/U', $content_part_value) === 1) {
                        if ($tds_inline_ad_paragraph_mob == $p_open_tag_count) {

                            $content_buffer .= td_global_blocks::get_instance('td_block_ad_box_mob')->render(array('spot_id' => 'content_inline_mob'));
                        }
                        $p_open_tag_count++;

                    }
                    $content_buffer .= $content_part_value;
                    $cnt++;

                }

            }
```

I want to wrap the code td_block_ad_box_mob between div. Which may look like this if its html `<div id="hello">td_block_ad_box_mob</div>`

Comment: You mean, you want to wrap the result of the method call `td_global_blocks::get_instance('td_block_ad_box_mob')->render(array('spot_id' => 'content_inline_mob'))` into a `div`? Well then append the opening tag before that, and the closing one after.

Comment: @misorude yes. it's the result of the php command right? if it is, then that's what I really want to wrap. how can I wrap it without getting any errors?

Comment: I tried adding

`$content_buffer .= '<div class="my_class">'td_global_blocks::get_instance('td_block_ad_box_mob')->render(array('spot_id' => 'content_inline_mob'))'</div>';`

but it just destroyed the page.

Comment: Now you just wrote a text literal and a method call right after one another, that is invalid syntax. You need to use the string concatenation operator `.` in between the parts: `$content_buffer .= '<div class="my_class">' . td_global_blocks::get_instance(…) . '</div>';`

Comment: @misorude hi. thanks for the quick answer. i honestly don't have enough knowledge with php and I'm glad you helped me with this question. your code solved my concern. thank you so much!